# How to prove these trigonometric vectors are an orthogonal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vectors

From paper [1], the authors claimed that "It is not difficult to prove that these basis vectors are not only linearly independet, but orthogonal as well." Here "these basis vectors" mean the column vectors from the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &   0   & 1 &  \dots & 1 \\
    \cos(x) &   \sin(x)  & \cos(3x) &  \dots & -1 \\
    \cos(2x) &   \sin(2x)  & \cos(6x) &  \dots & 1 \\
\cos(3x) &   \sin(3x)  & \cos(9x) &  \dots & -1 \\
    \dots  &  \dots  & \dots    & \dots & \dots  \\
    \cos((n-1)x) &   \sin((n-1)x)   & \cos((n-3)x) &  \dots & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Here x is $\pi/n$.

However, I am not able to prove this conclusion, could you please show me the procedure of proof or give me some hints?

[1] Rockhill, A. A., and T. A. Lipo. "A generalized transformation methodology for polyphase electric machines and networks." In 2015 IEEE International Electric Machines & Drives Conference (IEMDC), pp. 27-34. IEEE, 2015.

Comment: What is the scalar product?

Comment: @Raffaele It''s just like $1\times0+cos(x)\times sin(x)+...+cos((n-1)x)\times sin((n-1)x)$ for the first two column vectors, the scalar product of two finite vectors.

Comment: $$\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \sin (k x) \cos (k x)=\frac{\sin (n x) \sin (n x-x)}{2 \sin (x)}$$ and $$\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \sin (k x) \cos (3 k x)=\frac{\sin (n x) (\sin ((3 n-2) x)+\sin (n x))}{\sin (x) \cos (x)}$$ are not zero.

Comment: @Raffaele Sorry I forgot to mention x is pi/n, could you please explain more about how to obtain the above two equations?

Comment: https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/23/01/  and https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cos/23/01/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by orthogonality, we are using the $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ norm then if $v_i,v_j$ are two columns with $i\neq j$, one has
$$ \langle v_i, v_j\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\sum_{k=0}^n  \sin(2k x)\right)\;dx = 0$$
since each of the component has zero integral.